# Playwright : How to run the same test on multiple url in the same browser on different tabs and in parallel

Tags: playwright

I'm looking to run the same test for serverals url (~20) and I want to be the quickest as possible.

I would like to run my 20 tests in parallel in one browser and in a new tab (page) for each but I can't achieve it.

Here my code that open a new browser for each test :

```
const urlList: string[] = [
  'url1',
  'url2',
  ...
];

test.describe.parallel("Same test for multiple url", async () => {

  let context;

  test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
    context = await browser.newContext();
  });

  for (const url of urlList) {

    test(`${url}`, async () => {
      let page = await context.newPage();
      await page.goto(url);
    });

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel
Every worker starts it own browser.

If you put console.log("Log Before all"): in "Before All" you will see that it will be printed 20 times, in terminal. Even maybe you will expect to execute it only once.

So you must renounce something. You will have parallel execution or you will have one browser. Think that new browsers will not border you. :-)